# How to apply an operator to an array?

Tags: octave

The following returns two values:

```
$ octave --eval '[352, 475] ./ 1134 .* 100'
ans =

   31.041   41.887
```

Now I want to divide the two values.  I tried this but it does not work:

```
$ octave --eval 'divide([352, 475] ./ 1134 .* 100)'
error: 'divide' undefined near line 1, column 1
```

How to do this?

`feval` does not work:

```
$ octave --eval 'feval("/", [352, 475] ./ 1134 .* 100)'
error: feval: function '/' not found
```

Comment: You might not be able to do this on a single line. Typically you’d do `a = <your expression>` and then `a(1)/a(2)`.

Comment: I’m unclear why you want to evaluate something as an argument to the Octave program. Just write a script.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Almost every language has an `apply` function. I need to know how it is called in Octave.

Comment: What do you mean by "an `apply` function"? In C++ there's a `std::apply` that calls a function with a given set of arguments. Is that what you mean? That would be `feval` in Octave. But I don't see how that relates to the text in your post...

Comment: This is [apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply). And I want to apply the division to the two values.

Comment: The problem is that you have only one value, not two. Octave (the MATLAB langue) is fundamentally different from other languages in that the array is the fundamental data type. `5` is a 1-by-1 array, not an int or a double or whatever. So. you have a single value, the array `[31.041, 41.887]`, which you first have to split somehow into two arrays before you can call the division function on it. It *can* be done, but it'll be ugly and impossible to read. You're better off writing a script or a function M-file. Doing this in two statements is trivial.

Comment: Apply splits. It is its only job.

Comment: The Octave equivalent to a tuple or a list is the *cell array*. If `a={x,y}`, then `rdivide(a{:})` is the same as `x./y`. But you don’t have a cell array with two values, you have a single value. This is what I’m trying to convey. You think of an array as a set of values. It’s not. It’s a single value, a single unit. You can split an array into many arrays collected in a cell array with `mat2cell`. I hope you now understand why I’m saying this is complicated to do in one expression?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty ugly but seems to work.

```
$ octave --eval 'rdivide(mat2cell([352; 475] ./ 1134 .* 100, [1 1]){:})'
ans = 0.7411
```

Comment: if you use `num2cell` instead of `mat2cell` here, you don't need the extra DIM argument: `octave --eval 'rdivide( num2cell( [352, 475] ./ 1134 .* 100 ){:} )'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an anonymous function and call it on the spot:

```
octave --eval '(@(x) x(1)/x(2))([352, 475] ./ 1134 .* 100)'
```